# HorizontalTextAlignment is ignored after navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a simple app, where users can see more information in section, if they tab a Label, which is seen on the pictures below.

[image: The text is hidden]

[image: The text is shown]

The problem is, that after navigating to `AnotherPage` and back, the text moves to left, even though I have set the `HorizontalTextAlignment` to `End`.
This only happens, when I have shown the section and hiding it again (by tapping on the Label twice).
The problem is illustrated on the picture below, where `y` is located at the left side.

[image: After navigation]

My source code for showing a simple app with this problem, can be downloaded from [this Dropbox link.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/itvz541nnrr3i3y/TestApp.zip?dl=0)

***EDIT***
Added code example

The ContentPage is as simple as

```
<StackLayout>
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Label Text="Test" VerticalOptions="Start" />
      <Label Text="{Binding Text}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
         <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ChangeVisibilityCommand}" />
         </Label.GestureRecognizers>
      </Label>
   </Grid>

   <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}">
      <Label Text="Text 1" />
      <Label Text="Text 2" />
   </StackLayout>

   <Button Command="{Binding OpenAnotherPageCommand}" Text="Open Another Page" />

</StackLayout>
```

And the ViewModel is shown below

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private ICommand _changeVisibilityCommand;
   public ICommand ChangeVisibilityCommand
   {
      get => _changeVisibilityCommand;
      set
      {
         if (value != _changeVisibilityCommand)
         {
            _changeVisibilityCommand = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ChangeVisibilityCommand)));
         }
      }
   }

   private bool _isVisible;
   public bool IsVisible
   {
      get => _isVisible;
      set
      {
         if (value != _isVisible)
         {
            _isVisible = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsVisible)));
         }
      }
   }

   private ICommand _openAnotherPageCommand;
   public ICommand OpenAnotherPageCommand
   {
      get => _openAnotherPageCommand;
      set
      {
         if (value != _openAnotherPageCommand)
         {
            _openAnotherPageCommand = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(OpenAnotherPageCommand)));
         }
      }
   }

   private string _text = "u";
   public string Text
   {
      get => _text;
      set
      {
         if (!string.Equals(_text, value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
         {
            _text = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Text)));
         }
      }
   }

   public MainPageViewModel()
   {
      ChangeVisibilityCommand = new Command(() =>
      {
         IsVisible = !IsVisible;
         Text = IsVisible ? "x" : "y";
      });

      OpenAnotherPageCommand = new Command(() =>
      {
         (Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage)?.PushAsync(new AnotherPage());
      });
   }
}
```

And the `AnotherPage` is simply showing a text for example

Comment: Please take the time to post the relevant code and format it.  Don't expect others to take the time to download a zip, extract it, load the code into the IDE, and debug it for you.

Comment: I have added the code now sorry

Comment: this theory may be help you https://dzone.com/articles/xamarin-notesxamarinforms-layouts

Comment: @LasseMadsen Hi, did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i wasn't able to reproduce your issue using the latest version of Xamarin. Maybe simply upgrading Xamarin (Forms) will remove the unwanted behavior in your case as well.

If not, you have two options:

**1 - Use HorizontalOptions instead**

> HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"

since HorizontalOptions has a higher priority in the layout engine.
Not the most elegant way but surely the most reliable.

**2 - Use DataBinding**

In your model just add the following property:

```
    public TextAlignment LabelAlignment
    {
        get => labelAlignment;
        set
        {
            labelAlignment = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LabelAlignment)));
        }
    }
    private TextAlignment labelAlignment = TextAlignment.End;
```

And in your Xaml you change HorizontalAlignment to

> HorizontalTextAlignment="{Binding LabelAlignment}"

That will work because after your screen has been created, the values in the model will be loaded and updated afterwards.

Comment: I tried upgrading Xamarin.Forms on my Test App, but that did not work. 
Then I tried with setting HorizontalOptions to `EndAndExpand`, but that is not a possibility, as I need the Label to stretch across the whole page. And somehow the DataBinding did not work either

Comment: That is very strange. Your code worked on my system without any issues, also my DataBinding solution worked fine.

Did you upgrade Xamarin.Forms in your shared code only, or also on the native projects?
After loading your Solution, i had the version 3.0.0.482510 of Xamarin.Forms.
Maybe also try to make sure that your versions of MonoDroid and MonoTouch are at the latest version. 

I am using Visual Studio 15.7.3 Professional, if that is of any interest.

Comment: Okay, I am only using Community, but otherwise everything is up-to-date, but I found a fix now. If I set it to `Visible = false` in `OnDisappearing` and `Visible = true` in `OnAppearing` it works

Answer (score 0):

Change     `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"`

To   `HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"`

This will force the text to expand from the center and be placed at the end.

**To force the text to the right, you can add a another column definition to your grid:**

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Place and emtpy object into the first cell, the one to the left:

- number from the top (0)
- number from the  left (0)

and your label into the second cell, the one to the right:

- number from the top (0)
- number from the left (1)

The text area will adjust to the text length and will always be to the right.

I hope this information helps!

You can read more about grid in the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/grid-layout